# Is it possible to load all of AngularJS files (e.g. Controller, Factory) into an external HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, gruntjs, requirejs

There's an app I have been building, and as it grows, so does the `<script>` tag grows in the `index.html`

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="a.js"></script>
        <script src="b.js"></script>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Is it possible to include all of these `<script>` into an external html and then load it into `index.html` to use it? Like so.

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

        <script src="angular.js"></script>

        [**Include jsInclude.html here**]
    </body>
</html>
```

**jsIncude.html**

```
<script src="a.js"></script>
<script src="b.js"></script>
...
```

If so, what are some of the proper methods of performing such a task?

I have read online that I can use Grunt or RequireJS to load JS files dynamically.

However, I wish to avoid lazy loading, I want to load all of the JS files at once on startup.

Will using RequireJS or Grunt able to achieve this? Or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use webpack or browserify to compile all of your JS files into 1 JS file.

https://webpack.github.io/

http://browserify.org/

Grunt is just a task runner, it won't be able to do this task on its own.  You can set up a task in Grunt to run browserify/webpack

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be that way only. Load app.js first and then follow other files that include controllers, factories and so on in your HTML (index.html)﻿